# Why is my div not resizing in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to simply resize a div when I click on it, yet it's not resizing.  Can anyone tell me why?

**CSS**

```
#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#navigation").on("click", function(){
    $("#navigation").css("width", "100px");
})
```

Doing it this way does not work either.

```
$("#navigation").on("click", function(){
    $("#navigation").width(100);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

The console is not showing any errors.

Comment: It [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/vo0u03m4/). Check to make sure you're including jQuery (and that it's actually loading). Depending on where your script is located in your document, you may also need to wrap your JS with `$(document).ready(function () {...});` **Check the console..**

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6e0wj2Lg/. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code? Have you placed you code in a DOMReady handler?

Comment: jQuery's included and it works, I'm running some other functions as well.  Which is why I'm not understanding why this isn't.

Comment: Console's not kicking back anything

Comment: It is working. Other functions might have error and stopping it to execute. F12 and See errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#navigation').click(function () {
    $(this).css("width", "100px");
});
```